# Spring MVC - Jackson XML format

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I would like my controller to return the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <ResponseDTO result=”OK” timestamp=”20110322T152403Z">
 <myId>9999.99</myId>
 <currency>USD</currency>
</ResponseDTO >
```

Basically my DTO looks like this:

```
public class ResponseDTO {

    private String myId;
    private String currency;

}
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseDTO doSomething() {

   ...
   return new ResponseDTO();
}
```

I'm using the following dependency, gradle snippet given below:

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-xml', version:'2.8.2'
```

How is it possible to achieve the 'result=OK' and 'timestamp=20110322T152403Z' properties with jackson xml parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JacksonXmlProperty to set attributes to the jackson root element  like below:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement
public class ResponseDTO {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true)
    private String response;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="myId")
    private String myId;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="currency")
    private String currency;
}

Result: 

<ResponseDTO response="test">
<myId>test</myId>
<currency>test</currency>
</ResponseDTO>
```